# boost regex error: uninitialzed boost::match_results

Tags: c++, regex, exception, boost

When running the following

```
    bool my_compare(const std::string& string_1, const std::string& string_2)
    {
        const boost::regex str_re("so(m)e_(r)e(g)ex");
        boost::smatch str_match;     

        size_t one;
        uint8_t two;
        size_t three;
        if( boost::regex_search(string_1, str_match, str_re) ) {
            one = boost::lexical_cast<size_t>( std::string(str_match[1].first, match[1].second) );
            two = boost::lexical_cast<uint8_t>( std::string(str_match[2].first, match[2].second) );
            three = boost::lexical_cast<size_t>( std::string(str_match[3].first, match[3].second) );
        }
        size_t four;
        uint8_t five;
        size_t six;
        if( boost::regex_search(string_1, str_match, str_re) ) {
            four = boost::lexical_cast<size_t>( std::string(str_match[1].first, match[1].second) );
            five = boost::lexical_cast<uint8_t>( std::string(str_match[2].first, match[2].second) );
            six = boost::lexical_cast<size_t>( std::string(str_match[3].first, match[3].second) );
        }
        return false;
    }

    int main()
    {
       my_compare(some_string1, some_string2);
       return 0;
    }
```

I'm getting the following error, which I don't understand:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>
> > '   what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target

Comment: are `str_match` and `match` supposed to be the same? It helps to post code that compiles.

Comment: match[x] is generated by regex. str_match is the object used for the result

Comment: The code shown doesn't initialize or even declare anything called `match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `"so(m)e_(r)e(g)ex"`

This regex will populate capture `str_match[1]` with the string `"m"`, `str_match[2]` with the string `"r"` and `str_match[3]` with the string `"g"`

```
 boost::lexical_cast<size_t>( std::string(str_match[1].first, match[1].second) );
```

This will attempt to convert the string `"m"` into a value of type `size_t`, which fails ("m" is not an integer!), and throws the exception

> ' what(): bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target

(by the way, you don't need to jump these hoops with string constructor from a pair of iterators, submatches are directly convertible to strings)

Comment: the regex was an example which is not what I'm using. However, you helped me find the problem with casting. Thanks!